# How can I run curl as shell command line in PHP

Tags: php, curl

If I try to run this inside a script:

```
<?php exec("curl http://ww.google.com") ?>
```

I get:

```
-bash-3.2$ php test.php 
sh: /curl: No such file or directory
```

using shell_exec:

```
PHP Warning:  shell_exec(): Cannot execute using backquotes in Safe Mode...
```

How can I run curl as shell command line?

Those errors are happening on Linux, on my mac works.

Comment: Why not use the php curl library?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: It looks like your PHP server won't let you execute shell commands.  Are you running this locally or through a web host?  Also, why not use the CURL library?

Comment: curl is not supported on your server

Comment: It is a web server. I did not want to use CURL library and the script it was complete, so I do not want to waste time by rewriting the script with the library. I wish PHP had a decent REST library.

Comment: PHP's exec() environment will probably have a different path than your regular shell prompt. Try a full absolute /usr/local/bin/curl (or whatever) path for the curl executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `PHP` safe mode is on and it is better to use the full path to run `cURL` (thanks ghostJago and amosrivera). Running the script with the following command fixed the issue:

```
php -dsafe_mode=Off test.php
```

I do not want to change the `php.ini` but it could be a solution too.

`shell_exec` tells the safe mode problem, but `exec` just tell you an wrong message, hopefully I tried both `exec` and `shell_exec`.

Answer (score 3):

Disable `safe mode` in your php.ini file. Also check if you do have curl installed.

```
safe_mode = Off
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert from an bash command (like you can copy from chrome-dev-tools) to php take a look at this: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

at the commandline, do this:

```
which curl
```

This will give you the absolute path to the curl program.

Then double check that `safe_mode = Off` is in your php.ini.

When you've done this, change your code to:

```
<?php exec("path/you/got/from/which/curl http://www.google.com") ?>
```